# Logic for implications

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Example statement: Suppose we have a statement like : (P)Let S be a set... if (Q){other stuff}

So I was wondering what the example statement refers to exactly.

Is it Q -> P?

Because Q comes after the if(the hypothesis), and therefore P is the conclusion?

Comment: Your statement is not very clear to me. Perhaps, you could give a more explicit example.

Comment: Let S be the set of functions defined by putting $$g \in \mathrm{S}$$ if there exist positive constants $$c,a \in \mathrm{R}$$ such that |g(x)| <= c|f(x)| for all x > a.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it seems to me that you are writing a definition, and not a conditional statement.

I think that you are defining a *set* of functions :

> $S_f = \{ g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R | ∃c,a \in \mathbb R^+ ∀x((x > a) → (|g(x)| \le c|f(x)|) \}$.

I've "indexed" the name of the set in order to emphasize the fact that I've assumed that $f$ is a specific function.

If the definition is correct, it implies that :

> $g \in S_f ↔ [∃c,a \in \mathbb R^+ ∀x((x > a) → (|g(x)| \le c|f(x)|)]$.